# Why onEndReached setState is not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Before getting into the problem I wanna explain how I am getting data for my component first.

```
// Get List
  let productList = useSelector(state => state.productReducer.productList);

  
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(showCateory);
  const [numbersOfItem, setNumberOfItem] = useState(20);
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState(productList);

  useEffect(() => {
    setItemList(productList);
  }, [productList]);

  const renderIndividualItem = ({item}) => <IndividualItem item={item} />;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      setLoading(true);
      async function fetchData() {
        try {
          await dispatch(fetchProductList(numbersOfItem));
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } finally {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      }

      fetchData();
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

As you can see in the above code you can see that I am getting data from redux `useSelector store with redux hook`. I am requesting data to `API` whenever there is a change in `navigation`.

So Now is the flatList where the **PROBLEM** Is

```
<FlatList
           
         data={itemList}
         numColumns={2}
         nestedScrollEnabled
         columnWrapperStyle={styles.flatItemColumn}
         scrollEnabled
         ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
           <View style={styles.separatorWidth} />
         )}
         scrollEventThrottle={16}
         snapToAlignment="start"
         decelerationRate={'fast'}
         showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
         renderItem={renderIndividualItem}
         keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
         onEndReached={() => handleLoadMoreData()}
      />
```

As you can see I am running a function `handleLoadMoreData` when user reached to end of the flat list.

In the function I am requesting increasing the max number of item I am requesting

```
const handleLoadMoreData = () => {
    alert('function run')
    setNumberOfItem(40);
  };
```

I put an alert in the function so that I can detect whether the function run or not.

The thing is function do run because I got an alert but the `setNumberOfItem(40)` does not increase the number of item.

I made a `separate button` that `console log the number of items`. After Getting an alert when I press that button the number stills at 20 it doesn't increase at all.

I am getting the alert but why the number not increasing

Answer (score 0):

If setNumberOfItem is an action dispatcher make sure it is connected to the store

Answer (score 0):

In your useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
  setLoading(true);
  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      await dispatch(fetchProductList(numbersOfItem));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  fetchData();
});

return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

Add `numbersOfItem` to dependencies list like this:

`[navigation, numbersOfItem]`